# actions with empty array of objects in angular 9

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, object

I have two interfaces, Test and TestTwo; I have a func getTest() which return an empty array of Test[];
I use it on testArr in onInit, so now it's an empty array of Test type;
I need to get property text which is a type of TestTwo[], and on click write there an value; I need to write value exactly in prop subtext: string[]; Then display it in html

.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'arry';
  testArr: Test[] = [];
ngOnInit(){
  this.testArr = this.getTest();
}




    
    addRes() {
  console.log(this.testArr);

  for (const iterator of this.testArr) {
    iterator.text = [{subtext: ['a', ...subtext]}];

  }
 
    }

  getTest(): Test[]{
    let some: TestTwo[] = [];
    return [{
      text: some
    }];
  }
}


export interface Test {
  text: TestTwo[];
}

export interface TestTwo{
  subtext: string[];
}
```

.html

```
<div
*ngFor="let item of testArr; index as i"
>
<button (click)="addRes()">add</button>
<div *ngFor="let items of item.text; index as i">
  {{items.subtext}}
</div>
</div>
```

So, I need dynamicly add 'a' on button click, and also copy my previous values;

[stackBitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-g7kj5w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: I think you will need to explain better what you are trying to do (and maybe an exemple would be clearer)...

Also, testArr is an array, why use `Object.values(this.testArr)` on it ?

But I don't understand the core of your problem.

Comment: I have an testArr: Test[] with property text: TestTwo[]; In TestTwo is prop subtext: string[]; It's empty, I need to add some value there, for this example it's 'a'; And also copy old 'a' in this subtext

Comment: Please boil this down to an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I can't decipher what you want to happen. You don't need to show the whole component as it's more of a javasript question. Show your input and expected output.

Comment: There are two interfaces, Test and TestTwo; In interface Test I have a prop test which is a type of TestTwo[]; I created an array of type Test[]; In this array I need to write in SUBTEXT a value; Subtext is in interface TestTwo[]; Property TEXT is in interface Test; Text is a property of TestTwo[] type;

Comment: well IDK what the use of what you want to do, and it could be don much easier. but is this what you aim for ?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ej3mkv

Comment: I edited code, so for now I need to apologize for my question; My issue is in copy an subtext on each button click, and adding there a value

Comment: It's exactly that, ty

Comment: In the `addRes()` method you are iterating over `testArr` which is blank initially. Try with adding some value in the array in method `getTest()` . `let some: TestTwo[] = [{subtext: ['test1', 'test2']}];`.

Comment: I don't need to adding values on start, It must be an empty arr, I must to add values later on click in empty arr